# Alphanumeric and space regex but no space at start and end of string

Tags: javascript, regex, spaces, alphanumeric

I want to write a regex that may contains alphabets or number or spaces between word and must be of length between 3 to 50 but not spaces on start and end of string. This is my regex:

```
/^[^-\s]([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9\s-]){3,50}[^-\s]+$/i
```

Valid strings:

```
uma
umair
umair K
```

Invalid strings:

```
 uma
u
um
umair
```

The last example has a trailing space.

Comment: `/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9 ]{1,48}[a-z0-9]$/i` @ctwheels the post was edited after his comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(?=.{3,50}$)[^\W_]+(?: [^\W_]+)*$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the string
- `(?=.{3,50}$)` Positive lookahead ensuring between 3 and 50 characters exist before the end of the line
- `[^\W_]+` Match any word character except `_` one or more times
- `(?: [^\W_]+)*` Match a space followed by one or more word characters, any number of times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

```js
var r = /^(?=.{3,50}$)[^\W_]+(?: [^\W_]+)*$/
var a = [
  'uma','umair','umair K', //valid
  ' uma','u','um','umair ' //invalid
]

a.forEach(function(s){
  console.log(r.test(s) ? `Valid: ${s}` : `Invalid: ${s}`)
})
```

Alternatives:

```
^[^\W_][a-zA-Z\d ]{1,48}[^\W_]$
```

Comment: Nice!!, I like how you have broken it down.  The `^\W_` had me for a bit, but can now see this is a shorthand for `a-z0-9`

Comment: @Keith it's actually shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, so it saves 5 characters :)

Comment: The op was using the `/i` flag here.  But useful to know if wanting a mix without `/i`

Comment: very useful - they count lookahead is great

Answer (score 0):

A literal translation of your requirements looks like this:

```
!/[^a-zA-Z\d\s]/.test(str) &&
str.length >= 3 && str.length <= 50 &&
!/^\s/.test(str) &&
!/\s$/.test(str))
```

Why cram everything in one regex?